# Using smart card reader Gemalto IDBridge K30

Tags: drivers, card-reader, smartcard

I'm trying to use a smart card reader Gemalto IDBridge K30 in Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm not having success.

I do have `libccid`, `opensc-pkcs11` and `pcsc-tools` installed.

`pcsc_scan` does detect it:

```
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.5.2 (c) 2001-2017, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Gemalto USB Shell Token V2 (25D70BCC) 00 00

Sun Apr 12 16:01:08 2020
 Reader 0: Gemalto USB Shell Token V2 (25D70BCC) 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 7F 96 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 85 03 00 EF 12 0F FE 82 90 00

ATR: 3B 7F 96 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 85 03 00 EF 12 0F FE 82 90 00
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 7F, Y(1): 0111, K: 15 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 96 --> Fi=512, Di=32, 16 cycles/ETU
    250000 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 312500 bits/s
  TB(1) = 00 --> VPP is not electrically connected
  TC(1) = 00 --> Extra guard time: 0
+ Historical bytes: 80 31 80 65 B0 85 03 00 EF 12 0F FE 82 90 00
  Category indicator byte: 80 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 3, len: 1 (card service data byte)
      Card service data byte: 80
        - Application selection: by full DF name
        - EF.DIR and EF.ATR access services: by GET RECORD(s) command
        - Card with MF
    Tag: 6, len: 5 (pre-issuing data)
      Data: B0 85 03 00 EF
    Tag: 1, len: 2 (country code, ISO 3166-1)
      Country code: 0F FE
    Tag: 8, len: 2 (status indicator)
      SW: 9000

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 7F 96 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 85 03 00 EF 12 0F FE 82 90 00
3B 7F .. 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 .. .. .. .. 12 0F FE 82 90 00
        IDPrime MD 8840, 3840, 3810, 840 and 830 Cards T=0
3B 7F 96 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 85 03 00 EF 12 0F FE 82 90 00
        Gemalto IDPrime MD 840 (PKI)
        http://www.gemalto.com/Products/IDPrime_MD/index.html
```

But `pkcs11-tool` doesn't:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --verbose --test --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
No slot with a token was found.
```

And here's what `opensc-tool` has to say:

```
$ opensc-tool -n 
Using reader with a card: Gemalto USB Shell Token V2 (25D70BCC) 00 00
Unsupported card
```

I'd greatly appreciate of someone has ideas on how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist. but I have already configure a Gemalto cryptocard using the following methodology (Done with distrib debian jessie)
You need  to add 2 more packages **pcscd** et **opensc**.

```
apt-get install pcscd opensc
```

Pour valider les installations

```
pcsc_scan 
opensc-tool -a -n
# erase si la clef a déjà été utilisée
pkcs15-init -E -T <\code>
#create a new card
pkcs15-init --create-pkcs15 --profile pkcs15+onepin --label "Pénom Nom"
 # demande de pin
 # demande de PUK (récupératione en cas de blocage
```

create a RSA private/public key

```
pkcs15-init --auth-id 1 --generate-key rsa/2048 --key-usage sign,decrypt --label "Prenom Nom SSH Key"
# Be patient more than 30secondes}
```

TO see key structure:

```
pkcs15-tool dump
# just public keys
pkcs15-tool --list-public-keys
```

Use ID of the key to extract public RSA key from the card

```
# remplace with the good  ID done by pkcs15-tool --dump
pkcs15-tool --read-ssh-key b70000568953221
```